# Filtering rows of dataframe with multiple combinations of conditions in R

Tags: r, dplyr, filter

I am trying to filter & clean a large data frame (with columns x1 to x10 representing categorical variables) containing values 0 and 1, where 0 = FALSE and 1 = TRUE.

Example of the first 2 rows:

```
id | x1 | x2 | x3 |...| x10 |
---|----|----|----|---|-----|
1  | 1  | 0  | 0  |   | 1   |
2  | 0  | 1  | 1  |   | 0   |
```

The filter is based on multiple combinations of conditions for each row of data:

1. x1, x2, x3 are mutually exclusive (i.e. if a row contains TRUE for one of these columns, the other columns cannot be TRUE)
2. Neither x4 & x5 can be TRUE if any of x1, x2 or x3 are TRUE. x4 & x5 are also mutually exclusive.
3. Neither x7 & x8 can be TRUE if any of x1, x2, x3 or x4 are TRUE.

Rather than listing out all possible combinations of these conditions, is there a way to accomplish this more efficiently in R?

Appreciate any assistance.

Comment: `rowSums(DF[, paste0("x", 1:3)]) > 1L`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)

# create example data frame
set.seed(123)
n <- 1000
df <- data.frame(
  id = 1:n,
  x1 = sample(c(0,1), n, replace = TRUE),
  x2 = sample(c(0,1), n, replace = TRUE),
  x3 = sample(c(0,1), n, replace = TRUE),
  x4 = sample(c(0,1), n, replace = TRUE),
  x5 = sample(c(0,1), n, replace = TRUE),
  x6 = sample(c(0,1), n, replace = TRUE),
  x7 = sample(c(0,1), n, replace = TRUE),
  x8 = sample(c(0,1), n, replace = TRUE),
  x9 = sample(c(0,1), n, replace = TRUE),
  x10 = sample(c(0,1), n, replace = TRUE)
)
# Assuming your data frame is named 'df'
df_filtered <- df %>%
  filter((x1 + x2 + x3) <= 1,  # Mutually exclusive conditions for x1, x2, x3
         !(x4 == 1 & (x1 + x2 + x3) >= 1),  # x4 cannot be TRUE if any of x1, x2, x3 are TRUE
         !(x5 == 1 & (x1 + x2 + x3) >= 1),  # x5 cannot be TRUE if any of x1, x2, x3 are TRUE
         (x4 + x5) <= 1,  # Mutually exclusive conditions for x4, x5
         !(x7 == 1 & (x1 + x2 + x3 + x4) >= 1),  # x7 cannot be TRUE if any of x1, x2, x3, x4 are TRUE
         !(x8 == 1 & (x1 + x2 + x3 + x4) >= 1),  # x8 cannot be TRUE if any of x1, x2, x3, x4 are TRUE
         (x7 + x8) <= 1  # Mutually exclusive conditions for x7, x8
  )


    df_filtered
    id x1 x2 x3 x4 x5 x6 x7 x8 x9 x10
1    7  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1   1
2   14  0  0  1  0  0  1  0  0  1   1
3   23  0  1  0  0  0  1  0  0  1   0
4   29  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0   1
5   31  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  1   1
6   37  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1   1
7   39  0  0  0  1  0  1  0  0  1   0
8   49  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  1  1   0
9   63  1  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0   0
10  64  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0   1
11  69  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0   1
12  72  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0
13  83  0  0  0  0  1  1  0  0  0   0
14  96  0  1  0  0  0  1  0  0  0   0
15 107  0  0  0  0  1  1  0  1  1   0
16 123  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0   0
17 124  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0
18 128  0  0  0  1  0  1  0  0  0   0
19 129  0  0  0  0  1  1  0  1  0   1
20 153  0  0  0  0  1  1  0  1  0   0
21 160  0  0  0  0  1  0  1  0  1   1
22 189  0  0  1  0  0  1  0  0  0   1
23 199  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  1   0
24 204  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  1   0
25 230  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  1   0
26 241  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0   1
27 247  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  1   1
28 257  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  1   1
29 268  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  1  0   1
30 272  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  1   0
31 319  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1   1
32 335  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0   0
33 347  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  1   1
34 350  0  0  0  0  1  1  1  0  1   1
35 363  0  0  0  0  1  1  0  1  1   0
36 376  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0   0
37 390  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  1   1
38 406  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  1   0
39 431  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0   1
40 436  0  1  0  0  0  1  0  0  0   1
41 441  0  0  0  0  1  0  1  0  1   0
42 445  0  0  0  0  1  1  0  1  1   1
43 457  1  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0   0
44 470  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  1   0
45 471  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0   0
46 475  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  1   1
47 522  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0
48 525  0  0  0  0  0  1  1  0  1   1
49 542  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0   0
50 550  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  1  0   1
51 586  0  0  0  0  1  1  0  1  1   1
52 589  1  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0   0
53 597  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   1
54 605  0  0  0  0  1  1  1  0  1   1
55 611  0  0  0  0  1  0  1  0  0   0
56 630  0  0  1  0  0  1  0  0  0   0
57 631  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0   1
58 664  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0
59 665  0  0  0  1  0  1  0  0  0   1
60 679  0  0  0  1  0  1  0  0  0   0
61 688  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  1   0
62 734  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  1  0   0
63 735  0  0  0  0  1  1  0  0  0   0
64 740  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0   0
65 742  0  0  1  0  0  1  0  0  1   1
66 747  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0   1
67 783  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  1   0
68 788  1  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0   0
69 825  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  1   0
70 831  1  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0   1
71 855  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  1  1   0
72 856  0  1  0  0  0  1  0  0  0   0
73 867  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0   0
74 885  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0   0
75 892  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1   1
76 898  0  0  1  0  0  1  0  0  0   1
77 904  0  0  0  0  1  0  1  0  1   1
78 910  1  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  1   0
79 949  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  1   1
80 962  0  0  0  1  0  1  0  0  0   1
81 978  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0   0
82 998  1  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  1   0
```

Comment: An elegant solution - thank you!